Who is the referent of "him" in Genesis 18:2?

And the LORD appeared unto him in the plains of Mamre: and he sat in the tent door in the heat of the day; And he lift up his eyes and looked, and, lo, three men stood by him: and when he saw them, he ran to meet them from the tent door, and bowed himself toward the ground - Genesis 18:1-2

The usual understanding of Genesis 18 is that the LORD appeared to Abraham in the form of a man along with two other men.  It is usually expounded as either a theophany or a christophany.  This is never explicitly stated, however, and there are several problems that arise in the text when trying to apply this understanding throughout the passage.
For instance, in verse 9 "they (the men) said" and in verse 10 "he (the LORD) said" with no clarity regarding if it was two or all three of "them" who spoke.  In verse 22 the men turned and went toward Sodom while the LORD stayed with Abraham with no clarity as to how many of the three men went.  In verse 33 the LORD went his way yet in chapter 19 only two angels arrive in Sodom at evening time, neither one is identified as the LORD even though in 18:21 He had said He was going down to Sodom.  In 19:13 the two angels have been sent to destroy Sodom, whereas the mission of chapter 18 is for them to "go and see" such that the understanding that these two angels in chapter 19 are two of the men from chapter 18 is not explicit.
Additionally, at 12:7 (unspecified form), 13:14 (voice only?), 15:1 (in a vision), and 17:1 (unspecified form) the LORD appears to Abram and speaks to him and I've never heard anyone insisting that the LORD appeared as a man in those instances.  Therefore, it is likely that the LORD has and can appear in some other form than as a man (a smoking furnace and a burning lamp (15:17), for instance).
My question is: In 18:2, who is being referred to with "standing by him"?  Did three men appear standing by the LORD or by Abraham?  The usual interpretation has the three men standing by Abraham, with one of them being the LORD, but is this necessitated by the text or by the interpretation?
In other words, is there a textual or linguistic reason the passage must not be understood as, "The LORD appeared unto Abraham ... and Abraham lifted up his eyes and three men stood by the LORD"?
It seems odd that Abraham would run to meet them if they appeared standing by him.  However, if the three men appeared standing by the LORD this also meshes well with the rest of the passage.

If your interpretation were correct it must be applied to the former part of the verse as well as the latter. So, to whom do the following apply ? 1. 'He sat in the tent door ...' and 2. '... he lift up his eyes' ? If the referent shifts, then that to which the referent refers must be re-stated. This is not particularly a matter of Hebrew, it is a matter of concept and logic applicable to all spoken language. Nevertheless up-voted +1. for a good question.

I looked up the Hebrew word for run in Strong's Lexicon. It's number 7323. To run for whatever reason, especially to rush. Perhaps Abraham was "anxious" or "eager" to meet them. One thing is for sure, the Lord at vs1 literally appeared to Abraham along with two angels. Also, the Lord had an extensive dialogue with Abraham about Sarah and the outcome of Sodom. Vs33 "And as soon as He/God had finished speaking to Abraham the Lord departed; and Abraham returned to his place. At Genesis 19:1, "Now the two angels came to Sodom etc. The same being at Genesis 17:1-3 is the same being at Genesis 18:1

@Mr.Bond I have no doubt that the Lord appeared to him. What I'm wondering from the text is if the Lord appeared as something other than a man (like chapter 17 where it is unspecified), as one of the three men, or as all three.

There was a Presence (the Lord) seen not physically (no man hath seen God at any time) but known in faith and in Spirit. Then, also, there were three men. There is clearly significance in the number three, as representative.

Genesis 18:22 And the men turned their faces from thence, and went toward Sodom: but Abraham stood yet before the LORD. The men are gone. The Presence of the Lord is still with Abraham.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The matter at hand in Gen 18:2 hinges on the understanding of the Hebrew preposition, עַל (al) = "upon, above, over, by".
In Gen 18:2 is simply means "nearby" and NOT "immediately adjacent to".  That is, Abraham as liege of his huge household, was sitting at the entrance to his tent when he noticed three men standing nearby.
Being the hospitable man that he was, Abraham ran to greet them.  Thus, it appears they were perhaps a few dozen paces away.  This is well within the scope of the meaning of עַל (al).
Now, subsequently in the narrative, we learn more about these three "men",

one was the LORD Himself (Gen 18:1, 10, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 26, 29, 33)
two were angels (Gen 18:22, 19:1) who went to rescue Lot from Sodom

Thus, the first two verses of Gen 18 read (my translation) -

V1: And appeared to him [Abram] YHWH by the oaks of Mamre; and as he [Abram] was sitting [in] door of the tent in heat of the day
V2: and lifted his [Abram's] eyes and looked - and behold three men standing nearby him [Abram]; and [when] he saw and ran to meet them from door of the tent, and bowed himself [Abram] to the ground

Note that All the action reported in the narrative in Gen 18:1-5a is about Abram.  It is only when we get to Gen 18:5b that anything is reported about the three "men" who say, “Yes, you may do as you have said.”  That is, all the explicit pronouns up to V5a apply to Abram.
As to the identity of YHWH/The LORD, this is another question.  However, the identity of the pronouns in Gen 18:1-3 is unambiguous - it is Abram.

So is there something in the language that makes it impossible to read it as, "And the LORD appeared unto him (Abram) in the plains of Mamre: and he (Abram) sat in the tent door in the heat of the day; And he (Abram) lift up his eyes and looked, and, lo, three men stood by him (the LORD): and when he saw them (3 men), he ran to meet them from the tent door, and bowed himself toward the ground"

"Note that All the action reported in the narrative in Gen 18:1-5a is about Abram"  Not so.  The LORD appeared is the first action.

This word,  עַל (al), can also mean "in addition to", according to Brown, Driver, Briggs.  Is there a reason that it cannot mean this in the passage at hand?

@MikeBorden - "in addition to" would be non-sensical in this context as it would make the verse read; " ... and behold three men standing in addition to Abram ..."  Indeed, Abram was sitting.

I appreciate your patience here.  What if it is "The LORD appeared unto Abram ... and behold three men standing by him (the LORD)"?  Is this grammatically (or in some other way), impossible?

@MikeBorden - see my translation above:  The grammatical structure and subsequent narrative means that there are only three people - two angels and the LORD who appeared

Answer
The referent of “him” in Genesis 18:2 is Abraham.
Explanation
Chapter 18 begins with a general statement and then explains how all these things occurred.
Introductory statement:-
Yahweh appeared to Abraham when the latter was living in his tents at the oaks of Mamre.
How?:-
The remaining parts explain how this appearance took place.
One day three men approached Abraham.
(Most probably this happened on a Sabbath when Abraham was praying at mid-day. Holy people had this unwritten tradition of praying three times a day. See Daniel 6:10, 13 where Prophet Daniel prays three times a day and Acts 10:9 where Apostle Peter goes to the roof to pray at 12 noon).
Abraham immediately recognizes that one of the men is in fact Yahweh in human form.
[God is Spirit but He can manifest Himself in human form. See Jesus, after His resurrection, appears to two of His disciples in “another form” (Mark 16:12)]
Conversation ensues among them all.
They leave:-
The three men stand up to leave towards Sodom. Abraham accompanies them to a certain distance, probably till the town gate (verse 16).
While there, Yahweh reveals His purpose of action to Abraham (verses 20-21).
Two men leave:-
From that place, the two men (angels) go towards Sodom leaving Abraham and Yahweh behind.
(One person is referred as “man” and two persons are referred as “men”. So when two angels left, the Scripture says, ‘the men went to Sodom’. It doesn’t mean all three went!).
How do we know?
Genesis 19:1 says explicitly, “And the two angels came into Sodom at evening”. They came there in advance of Yahweh who stayed back with Abraham.
Also, the two angels say to Lot, “Jehovah has sent us to destroy it” (Gen 19:13).
Yahweh stayed back with Abraham:-
It is here that Abraham unsuccessfully pleads with Yahweh not to destroy Sodom.
After the conversation, Yahweh goes away and Abraham returns to his tent.
“And Jehovah went His way as soon as He had left off talking with Abraham. And Abraham returned to his place” (Gen 18:33).
Yahweh reaches Sodom:-
Next day morning, when Lot lingers hesitantly without leaving, the two angels catch hold of Lot, his wife and his two daughters and bring them outside the city (Gen 19:16).
It is here that Yahweh meets them. From verse 17 onwards it is Yahweh who is speaking to Lot.
How do we know that?

Until verse 17, it is the two angels who speak with Lot and are mentioned as “they”, “men”, “them”, “my lords” etc. But in verse 17 onwards it is Yahweh who speak as “He”, “I” etc.

In some literal translations we can see Abraham addressing Yahweh as “my Lord”. But in chapter 19, Lot calls the two angels as “my lords” (verse 2). But again, from verse 17 onwards, Lot calls Yahweh, whom he meets outside the city, as “no, Lord” (verse 18).

Verse 24 says: “And Jehovah rained brimstone and fire on Sodom and Gomorrah, from Jehovah out of the heavens”. So, Yahweh in human form in Sodom destroyed it utterly as per the command from Yahweh in heavens.


So, the narration ends here.
Conclusion

Genesis 19:24 proves that this was a Christophany.

When one of three men speaks, we say both, “he spoke” or “they spoke” without any error.

The two men went in advance and Yahweh followed them later.

“Stood by Abraham” simply means they appeared standing at the entrance of his tents compound. So Abraham ran towards them inviting them to enter his main tent.

So, the referent of “him” in Genesis 18:2 is Abraham.



You say, "Yahweh appeared to Abraham" in human form (your point 1 conclusion but Gen.19:24 does not prove that.) Christ is not the Father. As one comment to the OP suggests, all 3 men who appeared to Abraham left him to visit Sodom, leaving Abraham in the invisible presence of God the Father who had first appeared to him before the 3 men were seen. Yes, 1 of those 3 men could have been Christ but at evening 2 angels were in Sodom (looking like men). No Christophany then but, yes, Christ could have been 1 of the 3 mean appearing to Abraham. This is massively profound and deep.

@Anne – I never said Christ is the Father. Yes, all 3 men set out to Sodom and Abraham accompanied them (Gen 18:16) to some distance. At this spot (to where Abraham comes back next day morning), Yahweh stays back to talk to Abraham but the 2 men proceeded to Sodom (verse 22). [If 3 men went, only 2 came to Sodom (19:1). Where is the 3rd one? Missing? Lost his way?] it was not God the Father who appeared to Abraham because “no one at any time has seen God the Father” (John 1:18).

Now Gen 19:24 shows that the Yahweh on earth (Jesus) rained brimstone and fire from Yahweh (Father) out of the heaven. The Yahweh on earth (Jesus) is the same Yahweh who appeared to Abraham in human form. This is the Christophany. There is nothing to hint that it was an invisible presence. See, 3 men appeared to Abraham. But Abraham says to One only as my “Lord (Adonai)” (18:3 in singular!).

He didn’t say, “my lords” in plural. (But Lot said this in plural to the 2 angels in 19:2). This singular Abraham’s Lord (Adonai) is Yahweh and is offered water to wash His feet along with the angels’ feet!! So, it was a real appearance. Also, as I said, Abraham early next morning comes back to the spot “where he had stood there before Jehovah” (19:27); not in the invisible presence of Yahweh.

The OP asks, “Is there a textual or linguistic reason the passage must not be understood as, ‘The LORD appeared unto Abraham ... and Abraham lifted up his eyes and three men stood by the LORD’?” Based on the nuances of the preposition translated as “by,” the answer is no, the “him” by which the three men stand is not the Lord but Abraham. According to BDAG, when the preposition עַל (Strong’s H5921 meaning upon, above, over) is used with the verb נָצַב (H5324 meaning to take one’s stand, stand), the literal meaning is to stand over.
Brown-Driver-Briggs Lexicon

Strong’s
H5921

From the sense of inclining or impending over, על comes to denote contiguity or proximity, English by (or sometimes on):  — c.
Idiomatically, with עָמַד and נִצַּב to stand by (literally over, —
originally no doubt with reference to one supposed to be seated),
Genesis 18:2 three men נִצָּבִים עָלָיו standing by him, Genesis 18:8
and he עֹמֵד עליו standing by him under the tree, …


Based on the lexical discussion above and because of how the characters are positioned at the beginning of the story, the three men standing while Abraham is seated, Abraham is understood to be the object of the preposition עַל. The same wording is used again in verse 8 to describe how Abraham stands by/over the men to serve them (interlinear.
The OP states, “The usual understanding of Genesis 18 is that the LORD appeared to Abraham in the form of a man along with two other men. It is usually expounded as either a theophany or a christophany. This is never explicitly stated, however, and there are several problems that arise in the text when trying to apply this understanding throughout the passage.” I agree that there are problems with this interpretation, but the idea that the Lord should be counted separately from the three men is equally problematic. Apart from the ambiguity in v22, there is little evidence to support that there were ever more than three persons who appeared before Abraham. Whether or not the two angels in Genesis 19 are related to the three men in Genesis 18, the fact that there were only two is calculated, or so it seems, to prevent such a misunderstanding.
If “the Lord” is not counted separately, does “the Lord” refer to one of the three men? Or could “the Lord” refer to all three? The way the story is told, “the Lord” could refer to either all three men or to just one of the three. The passage goes to great lengths to maintain this ambiguity, even if doing so means having to forgo the norms of clear and logical storytelling.
The opaqueness in the narrative leaves room for a certain fluidity in how the identity of “the Lord” is understood. For instance, take v22 and the ambiguity with respect to the number of men that went toward Sodom. To be explicit on this point would provide clarity - such as regards whether or not the Lord is one of the three men - in a way that the passage is evidently unwilling to do.
These logical gaps in the story make it difficult to form any clear picture of the identity of the Lord. Attempts to do so tend to rely on assumptions that may or may not be consistent with the story. Consider the ambiguity in v10 and how the passage sidelines the conventions that govern pronouns and their antecedents. The “he” in v10 is plainly not the “he” in v9 (interlinear). While a change in speakers usually requires that the new speaker be identified, the antecedent of the “he” in v10 is not made clear.
Genesis 18:9-10 NKJV

9 Then they said to him, “Where is Sarah your wife?” So he
said, “Here, in the tent.”
10 And He said, “I will certainly return to you according
to the time of life, and behold, Sarah your wife shall have a son.”

Does “he” refer to “the Lord” in v1 or to “my lord” in v3? If so, why not state it clearly? Could “he” refer to the “they” in v9? Or is there another possibility? Some English translations replace the pronoun in v10 with “the Lord” (biblehub.com). While doing so helps to fill in the blank, such an interpretation is not without risk.
I believe the anomalies in the narrative are there for a reason. While I don't have the answer, I’ve come to the conclusion that the ambiguity in Genesis 18 is a central element of the story.  Clarity and logic may be great for presenting facts, but they are not so useful for portraying a mystery. This story of how the Lord appeared to Abraham is deftly crafted to convey just that, the ineffable mystery that surrounds the Lord’s person.

I'm an amateur at Ancient Greek but this looks like something that has arisen in translation.

Genesis 18:1-2
וַיֵּרָ֤א אֵלָיו֙ יְהוָ֔ה בְּאֵלֹנֵ֖י מַמְרֵ֑א וְה֛וּא יֹשֵׁ֥ב
פֶּֽתַח־הָאֹ֖הֶל כְּחֹ֥ם הַיֹּֽום׃
וַיִּשָּׂ֤א עֵינָיו֙ וַיַּ֔רְא וְהִנֵּה֙ שְׁלֹשָׁ֣ה אֲנָשִׁ֔ים
נִצָּבִ֖ים עָלָ֑יו וַיַּ֗רְא וַיָּ֤רָץ לִקְרָאתָם֙ מִפֶּ֣תַח
הָאֹ֔הֶל וַיִּשְׁתַּ֖חוּ אָֽרְצָה׃
And the LORD appeared to him by the oaks of Mamre, as he sat at the
door of his tent in the heat of the day.
He lifted up his eyes and looked, and behold, three men were standing
in front of him. When he saw them, he ran from the tent door to meet them and bowed himself to the earth

עָלָ֑יו=alaw is a 3rd person masculine singular preposition, agreeing with the subject of the sentence, which is Abraham.
In the previous verse, יֹשֵׁ֥ב=yashab=sitting was a participle agreeing with Abraham. The Lord appeared to Abraham as he was sitting. He has been the subject since Genesis 17:26. And the Lord obviously can't be the subject of וַיִּשְׁתַּ֖חוּ=he bowed himself toward the ground.
So!

The one by whom the three men stand is the one who lifts up his eyes
The one who lifts up his eyes is the one sitting
The one who bows down in v.18:2 is the one sitting in v.18:1
The tent we are in is Abraham's tent from 17:26-27
And the subject since 17:26 has been Abraham
So the subject changes only for 18:1a

וְה֛וּא=wehu="and he" marks a change of subject from God in 18:1a back to Abraham in 18:1b
At the start of וַיֵּרָ֤א=wayyera="And he appeared" there is also a consecutive vav. Not all of the consecutive vavs in the passage mark a change of subject, but the change only persists in one of the intervals between them. The passage is packaged-up into "this happened, then this happened".

And Genesis 32:24–30, where YHWH manifested himself as a human and wrestled with Jacob: "Jacob called the name of the place Peniel: for I have seen God face to face".

@Mr.Bond Eternity was the guest of history. The spirit is a guest of the body. The guest of Abraham was God. But wisdom will eat you out of house and home.

@RayButterworth How could YHWH manifest himself as a human when Jesus said at John 5:37 the Father cannot be seen, you have neither heard His voice at any time, nor seen His form. John 6:46, Not that any man hath seen the Father, except he who is from God, he hath seen the Father. 1 Timothy 6:16 says the same thing. At Genesis 16:13 Hagar said, "Then she called the name of the Lord who spoke to her, Thou art a God who sees, have I remained alive after seeing Him? So how do you reconcile both Hagar and Jacob seeing God when Jesus himself said God the Father cannot be seen? Who did they see?

@Mr.Bond asks "how do you reconcile both Hagar and Jacob seeing God when Jesus himself said God the Father cannot be seen?" — By not assuming that the YHWH of the Hebrew scriptures was the Father. Jesus was the JHWH; almost no one ever knew of the existence of the Father until Jesus revealed his existence. John 1:18 (RSV): "No one has ever seen God; the only Son, who is in the bosom of the Father, he has made him known.".

So you would agree that the angel of the Lord at Genesis 16:7 who multiplied Hagars descendants is the same being that multiplied Abrahams descendants at Genesis 17:1-3 who identifies Himself as the Lord God Almighty? Who is the "Us" at Genesis 1:26 and at Genesis 11:7? I will admit that the term "Father" in the OT at Isaiah 64:8 mainly refers to the Father as the creator. And of course the Son has made the Father known. The Father has no separate manifestation or  revelation of the Father. The Son reveals the Father in the OT and in the NT. This is deductive reasoning, not an assumption.
